# Trying to split data from one cell into multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to split data from one cell into multiple cells. A sample line of data would be:

## 7/21 6.98 2.18 CR 7/19-7/24

My goal is to make each piece of data appear in separate columns through a VBA macro. This is the code I have so far

```
Sub nameTest()

    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FullName As Variant

    txt = ActiveCell.Value

    FullName = Split(txt, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)
        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = FullName(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

My issue is that I cant figure out a way to make it run on each and every row, rather than just one row. Does anyone know how to do this? thank you for your time and help

Comment: A simple loop on the range from your `Activecell` to the last cell in that column would work as in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ColumnsB:F are available, perhaps:

```
Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Space:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1))
```

Comment: +1 But won't TTC default to `General` if you don't specify a format?  I think the only column I might specify would be the first column as `xlTextFormat`  or possibly as `xlMDYformat` depending on what the OP wants. I don't believe the column formats default to the previously used, unlike some of the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

**Codes:**

```
Option Explicit

'Method 1 - Fixed range
Sub nameTest()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        .Range("C1:G1").Value = Split(.Range("A1"), " ")

    End With

End Sub

'Method 2 - Dinamic range starting from C1
Sub nameTest()

    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        arr = Split(.Range("A1"), " ")

        .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(1, UBound(arr) + 3)).Value = arr

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]